# Hibernate - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

After configuring my Hibernate (JBoss Tools 4.3) configuration unsuccessfully, it doesn't show the Hibernate configuration with the name "Hibernate" on the list in the Hibernate perspective. When I try to add a new Hibernate configuration with the same name, eclipse says that a configuration with that name already exists, but I can't see it.

So I closed my Eclipse Luna and when I try to open it again, Eclipse ask for my workspace path, I click on OK and then the workspace doesn't open again.

I cannot believe that the Eclipse became corrupted after configuring the Hibernate reverse eng.

I found many videos and pages that show how to use hibernate but I recently downloaded the version 5.1.0 which has the jars in required and model generator 5.1.0.

First question, how can I fix my eclipse in order to open it again. It is running in background in processes in windows but it is not displayed (I've already restarted my PC)? Do I have to delete manually configuration of Hibernate in Windows Explorer?

Second, how can I generate my classes from data model for the version 5.1.0? I cannot find any tutorial for this version.

I must tell that I've never used this framework before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experienced the same issue(starts and crashes) with Eclipse. In Task manager I was able to see its running. Try deleting the folder and see if it makes any difference. This fixed my eclipse

...\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench"

Comment: Thanks. It worked. My eclipse workspace opened again. But you know any tutorial in 5.1.0 to use hibernate?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't have any tutorials for specific version. I am using eclipse helios with hibernate (4.3.5.Final)without any issues. Not sure if you can download your version. Are you using Maven to add dependencies for the project?